# Facebook messenger API throws error after deprecation

Tags: php, html, facebook, message

I'm suddenyly getting errors in my facebook messenger service that sends messages from my website to a facebook chat. The error is 
`"type":"OAuthException","code":10,"error_subcode":2018278,"fbtrace_id":"AJSz9EQPjUFjShr0QK34yEr"}} {"error":{"message":"(#10) This message is sent outside of allowed window. Learn more about the new policy here:`

I have seen this note on the facebook API pages `On March 4th, 2020 we introduced Messenger webhook versioning with v6.0 having the first versioned change for the messages field.`

Here is my code for sending a message

`
              $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=';

```
            /* initialize curl */
            $ch = curl_init($url);
            /* prepare response */
            $jsonData = '{
                "recipient":{
                    "id":"' . $sender . '"
                },
                "message":{
                    "text":"' . $message . '"
                }
            }';
            /* curl setting to send a json post data */
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
            if (!empty($message)) {
                $result = curl_exec($ch); // user will get the message
            }`
```

Can someone explain what FB has changed to make this not work and what the new alternative is or how I can correct my own code.

Thanks

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/changelog/

Comment: _“This message is sent outside of allowed window.”_ means you are trying to send a message in a situation, where you are not allowed to do so any more. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy/policy-overview has a quite extensive explanation of what you can send when.

Comment: I'm just wondering which one I use now that it's March 4th and they have deprecated some of the messaging services.

Comment: What does this have to do with anything having been deprecated, the error message is about you trying to send a message outside of the allowed time frame.

Comment: Oh wow thanks, you're right. It was working until the 4th so thought their changes had screwed me over.